# Can 64 GB micro SD card be used for software installation in ASUS X205ta?

Tags: sd-card, asus-laptop

I have bought an ASUS X205ta which comes with 32 GB SSD storage. As 32 GB storage is very small, I am planning to put a 64 GB micro SD card in it. Is it possible to install software (like Skype, Viber etc. ) on that 64 GB micro SD card?

If I put a 64 GB micro SD card, then will I have a total of (32 + 64) = 96 GB of storage space where I can install software  **OR** will I have only 32 GB space for software installation?

Comment: The internal 32GB eMMC is apparently soldered in.  It contains Win 8.1, a recovery partition, and the software that comes bundled with it, leaving 14 GB available.  You could load additional software on that.  The card reader is MicroSD/MicroSDXC/MicroSDHC, so it should take a 64GB card.  All of that would be available for storage.  I couldn't find anything definitive on installing and running software on it.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to install whatever you want to it, whether that be programs, files, etc... it will be treated as any other drive/partition. The only exception is that it won't be the "main" drive so when installing programs you may have to manually change the installation destination. Work-arounds exist for solving this inconvenience though.

If you're considering using Micro SD Cards as a storage medium for your computer's operation (via SD Card slot) I strongly suggest looking into the various Speed Classes of SD cards, seeing as how some are much slower than others. The following link provides the simply information needed in determining differences between cards.

https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/speed_class/

Answer (score 0):

You can install almost whatever you want, it's like you have another partition on your laptop.

I have a 64GB MicroSD class 10 and I've got all my programs on it. For things like movies, pictures, and documents I just use the cloud.

I would also recommend keeping that SD card only for the laptop. If you want to use it for a camera I recommend formatting it first, because I got some software issue with my camera because of the Windows DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop comes with Windows 10 S, it has restricted software.  "Microsoft is switching its approach to Windows 10 S, its new version of Windows that's designed to compete with Chrome OS. The software giant originally announced Windows 10 S as a dedicated version of Windows for education customers that's **restricted to running Microsoft Store apps**."

If you have any other version of Windows 10, you're ok with installing almost anything.